# Multiple locator for finding webelement with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, qaf

I am using Selenium Webdriver with [QAF](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf).
The issue I am facing is related to finding an element on webpage.
for few of elements, different locators work at different times.

For example - sometimes name=nameA works and sometimes name=nameB(may be depending upon different environments of AUT, I have no clue).

Find code below:

```
public class HomePage extends WebDriverBaseTestPage<WebDriverTestPage> {


    @FindBy(locator="name=nameA")
    private QAFWebElement btnSomeElement;


    @Override
    protected void openPage(PageLocator locator, Object... args) {
        driver.get("/");
    }
}
```

What should I do to come over this issue?

Comment: Is it different locator for different environment/platform case?

Comment: yes, for separate environments like QA/Staging/Prod locators changes, and I dont want to overload with long xpath or other strategies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you are already using QAF you already have solutions available for such use case. First of all you should use Locator repository,
Instead of hard-coding locator in page just provide locator key.

For example:

> **In page.loc** File
>
> ```
> my.ele.locator=<locatorStretegy>=<locator>
> my.ele.locator=name=elemName
> ```
>
> **In Page class:**
>
> ```
> @FindBy(locator = "my.ele.loc")
> private QAFWebElement btnSomeElement; Now coming to your problem, if most of the locator very with environment then you can utilize
> ```
>
> [resource management capabilities of QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html). In other case you can
>   use [alternate locator strategy](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locating_elements.html#alternate-locator) provided by QAF. For example:
>
> ```
> my.ele.locator=['css=.cls#eleid','name=eleName','name=eleName2']
> my.ele.locator=['name=eleNameEnv1','name=eleNameEnv2']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should get a selector that matches both environments, use css or xpath selectors.

Add html snippet with the sections/elements if you need any help.

Assuming that you are selecting by name and this name changes, you can write a selector that matches both names like:

css:  `[name=nameA], [name=nameB]`
xpath: `//*[@name='nameA' or @name='nameB']`

Comment: this becomes difficult sometimes to provide locator for example, case of mobile native especially iOS

Answer (score 0):

It is very common that the locator changes sometimes. Some are even dynamic especially elements in the table rows. It is better to use more specific locator like xpath to locate the element.

```
@FindBy(locator = "xpath=//button[text()='ButtonName']")
private QAFWebElement btnSomeElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.login.page.logon.button = {\"locator\":[\"xpath=//div[contains(@id,'logonbutton')]//span[contains(text(),'Logon')]\",\"xpath=//*[contains(text(),'Logon') or @id='__screen0-logonBtn']\"]}
```

This is an example of the same for plain text file using multiple locators in QAF. Works for me.