# Can we declare an element in Selenium with more than one reference?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

In my current framework (Cucumber, Selenium webdriver, PageObject), we are declaring elements as below

**CreateProfile.java //file name**

```
public class CreateProfile {
    private static final By FIRST_NAME = By.id("firstNmae");
    private static final By LAST_NAME = By.id("lastNmae");
    private static final By CLICK_SUBMIT = By.xpath(".//span[@title='{submit}']");
}
```

followed by methods to enter and click elements.

I want to pass more than one element reference like this

```
private static final By CLICK_SUBMIT = By.xpath(".//span[@title='{form_submit}']") || By.id("submit") ;
```

What to do if I want to pass more than one element reference for same element as above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following `css selector`.which will identify the element

```
private static final By CLICK_SUBMIT = By.cssSelector("span[title='{form_submit}'],#submit");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'OR' logic using pipe (`|`) in Xpath:

```
private static final By CLICK_SUBMIT = By.xpath("//(span[@title='{form_submit}'] | *[@id='submit'])")
```

And if you are using `FindBy` you might want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66471251/how-to-find-elements-with-findby-if-they-have-multiple-id-values/66471355#66471355) as well.

Comment: It's working as expected for me.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Selenium provides `ByAll` implemaneation of `By` for such cases. Say you have a class with `By`s:

```java
class MyBys {
    public static final By CLICK_SUBMIT_BY_TITLE = By.xpath(".//span[@title='{submit}']");
    public static final By CLICK_SUBMIT_BY_ID = By.id("submit");
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```java
By mySuperBy = new ByAll(MyBys.CLICK_SUBMIT_BY_TITLE, MyBys.CLICK_SUBMIT_BY_ID);
driver.findElement(mySuperBy).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is available with QAF as [alternate locator strategy](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locating_elements.html#alternate-locator).
You can refer [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662786/multiple-locator-for-finding-webelement-with-webdriver). The code will look like below:

```
//if my_ele_loc in properties file
driver.findElement("my_ele_loc").click();

//if my_ele_loc is declared in java
driver.findElement(my_ele_loc).click();
```

`my_ele_loc` can either in locator repository out side code or in java code. It will look like:

```
#out side code in property file
my_ele_loc=['id=submit','xpath=.//span[@title=\'{form_submit}\'']

//java code
public static final String my_ele_loc="['id=submit','xpath=.//span[@title=\'{form_submit}\'']"
```